# Configure TeamCity Build Configuration to Trigger Only After Multiple Successful Builds in Chain

Tags: teamcity

We are currently running `TeamCity Enterprise 2017.1.5 (build 47175)` and are trying to set up the following set of steps for our build:

- On initial kick-off, run a build configuration `Step 1`
- If `Step 1` succeeds, kick off the build configurations `2A`, `2B`, and `2C` simultaneously
- If **all** steps (`2A`, `2B`, and `2C`) succeed, kick off build configuration `Step 3`

Essentially, we are attempting to speed up our overall build time by allowing multiple build configurations to run in parallel to each other. The `2` configs all can run independently as long as `Step 1` succeeds, so we set them all up to trigger after `Step 1` successfully builds.

However, `Step 3` is essentially a deployment build configuration. That should only run if all previous configs (`Step1`, `2A`, `2B`, `2C`) succeed.

Is there a way to set up Build Configurations in TeamCity so that we can achieve our setup for `Step 3` outlined above? I made a little image below to illustrate our desire.

[image: Build Flow]

Comment: Imho this is not possible with a single build configuration with 5 steps, but it is quite easy to achieve, with 5 build configurations, each with 1 step. Check this: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Build+Dependencies+Setup

Comment: Apologies @Peska , but yes I did mean 5 build configurations as opposed to a single configuration w/5 steps. I'll edit my post to clarify. And the provided documentation seems to have the solution: Use Snapshot Dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [Dependencies](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Dependent+Build).

1) Extract `step 3` and `step 1` as other build configurations. (For example, let's say `build 3` and `build 1`)

2) open Build Configuration settings for `2A`, `2B`, `2C`, go to **Dependencies**.

Add **Snapshot Dependency** to `build 1` 
[image]

Add **Artifact Dependency** to `build 1` with params 
**Build from the same chain** (it's important point!!!)

---

Open Build Configuration settings of `build 3`
Add 3 **Snapshot Dependency** to `2A`, `2B`, `2C` as the previous step. 
Add 3 **Artifact Dependency** to `2A`, `2B`, `2C` with params **Build from the same chain** as the previous step

In the end, you will achieve results. The TC will rebuild only if some configuration has changes, otherwise reused the existed.

See my configuration dependencies

Deploy all configuration redeploys the Cassandra DB and redeploys 2 builds.

`Deploy 1` and `Deploy 2` needs Cassandra results and artifacts from the builds. So, both of Deploys need Cassandra but separately needs a build. 
[image]

Comment: I had them as separate configurations already, but indeed Snapshot Dependencies was the trick. (Artifact Dependencies aren't even needed unless you have artifacts, which isn't the case for me).

Comment: Please note that if both a snapshot dependency and an artifact dependency are configured for the same build configuration, in order for it to take artifacts from the build with the same sources, the Build from the same chain option must be selected in the artifact dependency.

Answer (score -1):

This should be a separate build steps in Team city, team city could run only a build step at a time for a build or a runner. This 2a, 2b and 2c should be split into steps 2, 3 and 4 respectively.
Team city doesn't to parallel building within a runner